# Parameter generator for SCHTASKS.exe

Tags: windows, linux, unix, cron, windows-task-scheduler

I've came across many websites providing functionality for creating crontab parameters from user input through a GUI like..

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jslibrary/demos/crontab.php
and many others, I was wondering if there is a same kind of thing available for Windows utility schtasks.exe?

Or if the the parameters for SCHTASKS.exe can be reverse engineered by first defineing a task in Task Scheduler(GUI) in Windows?

Comment: schtasks and task scheduler should be the same, so task scheduler is actually the gui for schtasks that you are looking for

Comment: You are right...but it can not reverse engineer the parameters required by the command line utility shttask.exe

Answer (score 1):

**schtasks /query /xml**  generates an XML with all the options that defines the task